# Try to hide mailchimp inputfields after successfull submitting?

Tags: jquery, mailchimp

I couldn't find an answer on mailchimp and i thought i would be simple. Just checkin if the succes-response div has any value and hide the div's.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").click(function (e) {
            if ($('#mce-success-response').text().length > 0) {
                $('#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group').hide();
                alert('hide hide the fields');
            } 
        });
    });
```

But this doesn't work, the response happens after the click event. So how can i make it to work??

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the fields first in the click function, and then redisplay them if the length of the success response does not indicate success.

Hiding might be a little harsh visually...maybe fade out their opacity or use a slide toggle to make the form go away to a swirling 'please wait' image.  The sky is the limit.

Comment: hi luke,

But then i need to validate the fields first and i would like to avoid that.

Comment: I would imagine then the solution may be to try and attach a listener to whatever is sending back the success response which goes in that id, or to perhaps monitor that id for any changes.